# Call a function written in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

But the function i have written in external javascript file cannot be used in html.

here is my js code(index.js):

```
 function read(){
console.log("read function");
}
```

also tried this:

```
(function(){
 this.read=function(){
  console.log("returning data ");
 }
})()
```

And my html code is:

```
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Testing with JSClient</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="example1()">Query</button>
    <script src="./index.js" type="javascript"></script>

 <script type = "text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
    read();
    }
    function example1() {
    read();
   }
  </script>    

  </html>
```

this gives error as

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: read is not defined
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you copy & paste it here?

Comment: *this gives error* cool. At least have a deeper look on it, and tell us what it says and where it occurs. And basically your code would work. Have you checked the script is properly loaded?

Comment: you need to include the function javascript file to html file

Comment: i added image of error here but i wont visible so edited question.too soon downvote

Comment: My guess is the external javascript file is not actually loading

Comment: @Jamiec first isnt working too.neither on window.onload nor on button client

Comment: @jamiec im quite shure that either both work or not.

Comment: Open up the network panel, do you see a 200 for the js file?

Comment: so how to check it.if it isnt loading y it isnt giving error of not finding file

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: status is "Finished"

Comment: get rid of the type attribute on the script tag.

Comment: @epascarello great answer.please add an answer so that i can upvote it.:)

Answer (score 3):

You need to get rid of the `type="javascript"` on the script tag. That is not a proper value so the script is not executed.

Example that will work:

```js
$("#foo").html("hi");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

and with the attribute, throws an error:

```js
$("#foo").html("hi");
```

```html
<script type="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Yep `If the MIME type specified is not a JavaScript type the content embedded within its tags is treated as a data block which won't be processed by the browser.` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: Hey i have same issue.including simple JS functions to html file.this cannot solve my problem.i tried window.onload which calls function once but cannot get this function called on button's click event.